# Understanding Eager Loading - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to understand the concept of eager loading and what better way than implementing the concept right into an actual app. As I was trying this I ran into a problem. I'm getting this error when I try to load my `assignment` show page: `undefined method "includes" for #<Assignment:0x007f82f6e41210>`. I thought that if you `include` an association that is the concept of preloading so that you don't have to make multiple trips the the database? But clearly I'm doing something wrong here. Any help would be great here is my code and models that apply:

### Timekeeper.rb

```
class Timekeeper < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :assignment

  validates :assignment_id, presence: true
end
```

### Assignment.rb

```
class Assignment < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :description, presence: true

  belongs_to :account
  has_many :tasks
  has_many :assignment_relationships
  has_many :users, through: :assignment_relationships
  has_many :timekeepers

  def assigned_workers
    assignment_relationships.where(designated: true).count
  end
end
```

### Assignment Controller:

```
  def show
    @assignment = current_account.assignments.find(params[:id]).includes(:timekeepers)
    @tasks = @assignment.tasks.all
    @task = @assignment.tasks.new
  end
```

Additionally how would I call this in the view once it works? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> undefined method "includes" for #< Assignment:0x007f82f6e41210>

This means you are trying to call includes on an `Assignment` instance where as you must be chaining it to `ActiveRecordCollection`

You need to change the order of your methods use `includes` and then `find`.

```
def show
  @assignment = current_account.assignments.includes(:timekeepers).find(params[:id])
  @tasks = @assignment.tasks.all
  @task = @assignment.tasks.new
end
```

This will return you a single record of `Assignment` with `id = params[:id]` and will also eager load all the associated `timekeepers`.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting this error because you're trying to use `includes` on a single object, `find` returns a single object in this statement.

```
@assignment = current_account.assignments.find(params[:id]).includes(:timekeepers)
```

You can do however this, because `where` returns an activerecord relation and you can do `includes` on that. Whether it makes sense to do this in your case you'll have to decide.

```
@assignment = current_account.assignments.where(id: params[:id]).includes(:timekeepers)
```